# Cygwin, OpenSSH and Gitosis on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssh, cygwin, git

I spent serveral hours getting Cygwin, OpenSSH and Gitosis to work together on Windows Server 2008 x64 - unfortunately the tutorials on the web (from e.g. Shannon Cornish) don't seem to have an answer to my problem.

I get the following trying to login to my "git" user via SSH or trying to checkout the repository via "git clone git(at)localhost:gitosis-admin.git"

```
[main] sshd 9364 C:\cygwin\usr\sbin\sshd.exe: *** fatal error - could not load user32, Win32 error 1114 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I found some hints that the I have to set serveral group policies regarding user tokens - but doing so didn't help either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into the same problem, both with [Shannon Cornish's approach](http://www.shannoncornish.com/blog/2009/04/git-server-windows-2008/) and with [Tim Davis' approach](http://www.timdavis.com.au/git/setting-up-a-msysgit-server-with-copssh-on-windows/).  I'm still stuck.

Have you  tried Tim Davis' approach as well?  I've read on various cygwin-related sites that if the SSH daemon is running (indirectly) as a Windows administrator then this problem goes away.  I'm running cygwin/sshd as a user who's in the admin group, so has full privileges to all files but I still get the same Win32 error 1114 as you.

Please post back if you've resolved the problem or if any of either of my pointers works for you.

**Edit:**

A [Cygwin dev describes the relationship between cyg_server, Win32 errors, and Domain security](http://lists-archives.org/cygwin/52010-why-you-can-t-load-ws2_32-dll-was-can-t-use-key-authentication-on-x64-server-2003-r2.html).  I haven't fully ruled this out as the cause but in my case I'm not trying to SSH using a Domain user so it sounds like it wouldn't be an issue.

Also, in case it helps: [Mark Embling describing similar setup to Shannon's but continuing into more detail on Gitosis](http://www.markembling.info/view/git-server-gitosis-and-cygwin-on-windows)

Comment: Simon B's answer worked for me.  I had originally configured cyg_server and SvcCOPSSH to be in the Administrators group but adding the git user did the  trick.  Would vote Simon B up  but don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: Thanks for the hint I'll try getting it to work later this week - I had a project that needed to get done, so I decided to use a Debian VM as a temporary solution.

Comment: None of these helps.  I even tried checking with Process Monitor--nothing special there.  The solution is to add git to "Administrators" group, and disable logging in with sshd built-in capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error and solved it by giving my "git" ssh user membership in group Administrators.
The hint to do this came from http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2008-07/msg00276.html

Comment: Actually this is something I'd like to prevent for security reasons - but I'll give it a try to see if it helps at all in my case.